# Wikipedia pageviews analysis

Tags: analysis, wikipedia, pageviews

I've been challenged with wikipedia [pageviews](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/) analysis. For me this is the first project with such amount of data and I'm a bit lost. When I download the file from the link and unpack it, I can see that it has a table-like structure with rows looking like this:

```
1   |  2                             |3|4

en.m The_Beatles_in_the_United_States 2 0
```

I struggle with finding out what exactly can be found in each column. My guesses:

language version and additional info (.m = mobile?)

name of the article

The biggest concern I have with two last columns. The last one has only "0" values in it and I have no idea what it represents. I'd assume then that the third one show number of views but I'm not sure.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me to understand what exactly can be found in each column or recommend some reading on this subject. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need the pageview data for every page? There are easier ways to get the data if you need it on a smaller scale.

Comment: Yes, I need all of them. I want to analyze general trends like top performers, traffic on the website etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more time spent on this, I've finally found solution. I'm posting this in case someone has the same problem in the future. Wikipedia explains what can be found in database. These explanations were painful to find but you can access theme [here](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/Data_Lake/Traffic/Pageviews) and [here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Learning_patterns/Tips_for_reading_project_codes_from_pageviews_data_files).

Based on that you can see that rows have following structure:

- domain code
- page_title
- count_views
- total_response_size (no longer maintained)

Some explanations for each column:

Column 1:

> Domain name of the request, abbreviated. (...) Domain_code now can
>   also be an abbreviation for mobile and zero domain names, in which
>   case .m or .zero is inserted as second part of the domain name (just
>   like with full domain name). E.g. 'en.m.v' stands for
>   "en.m.wikiversity.org".

Column 2:

> For page-level files, it holds the title of the unnormalized part
>   after /wiki/ -in the request Url (E.g.: Main_Page Berlin). For
>   project-level files, it is - .

Column 3:

> The number of times this page has been viewed in the respective hour.

Column 4:

> The total response size caused by the requests for this page in the
>   respective hour.  If I understand it correctly response size is
>   discontinued due to low accuracy. That's why there are only 0s. The
>   pagecounts and projectcounts files also include total response byte
>   sizes at their respective aggregation level, but this was dropped from
>   the pageviews and projectviews files because it wasn't very accurate.

Hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: Hi Piotr, I'm on the Analytics team at the Wikimedia foundation and I'd be curious what we could do to make it easier to find these docs.  Maybe the best place to discuss would be on this task: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T201653

Comment: Sure, I'll try to contribute to discussion. My first impression was that I would normally expect at least the link to docs on the site where data is available. It was not the case so I wasn't even sure if documentation exists. I mean there where some explanations but they ended rather vague. Additionally doc page wasn't positioned in Google very high.

Comment: I see.  I think Google has a hard time because the content is very common (many people have pageview tools and definitions).  The best advice I can give for that is if you search Analytics stuff for WMF to prefix it with "wikitech" which is where all our docs are.

As for the docs close to the data, it turns out there was a technical problem with the readme, that we now fixed, does that help? https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/readme.html

Comment: I've checked the link and everything is very clear for me. It's amazing that you've decided to take the effort to fix it. Thank you on behalf of Wikipedia data users! :)

Comment: These small things are very important, and very easy, it's the bigger things that are harder to prioritize.  But if you have small annoyances that we can help with, please don't hesitate to reach out.  Thanks for the thoughts and help.

Answer (score -1):

> Line format:
>
> - wiki code (subproject.project)
> - article title
> - monthly total (with interpolation when data is missing)
> - hourly counts

(From [pagecounts-ez](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-ez/) which is the same dataset just with less filtering.)

Apparently buggy though; it takes the first two parts of the domain name for wiki code, which does not work for mobile domains (which are in the form `<language>.m.<project>.org`).

Comment: Thank you for helping but it turned out that actual line format goes like this: domain_code; page_title; count_views; total_response_size. You can see my explanations below. Thanks for your input!